# Change pointer to NSString in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsstring

I have been experimenting a bit with Objective-C and noted some, at least to me, rather strange behavior. First I define a pointer to an NSString and add it to an NSArray:

```
NSString *s = @"A";
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithOject: s];
```

I then print out the value of s as well as the contents of a:

```
NSLog(@"%@", s);
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

and in both cases the output is A. Now, if I change the pointer s, say

```
s = @"B";
```

then the two NSLog statements print out B and A, respectively.

That is, the pointer in my array still points to `@"A"`. After spending years coding in Java, this is very surprising to me. Am I missing something really fundamental here?

Thanks,
Michael Knudsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this is that `@"A"` creates a new NSString object.

In your code, you set the pointer s to point to this object, and then add the original object (not the pointer) to an array.  You then change the address that the pointer points to to a new address.

If you want to change the original object, then use NSMutableString and **modify** the actual object (instead of changing the pointer to a new object) and they will both update as you expect.

Try:

```
 NSMutableString *s = @"A";
 // Add to array
 [s setString:@"B"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because NSStrings are immutable, as in Java, so you are not changing the contents of the object stored at address x (the one nsarrsy has), you are pointing s to address y.

Comment: I have tried using a mutable string instead: NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"A"]; but the problem persists. Is that still to be expected?

Comment: Yes, then do: [s setString:@"B"];

Comment: So whenever I add a pointer to an NSArray, it actually makes a copy of that pointer?

Comment: @Michael: I think my answer explains what it is doing. You are adding the original object to the array, not the pointer.

Comment: You're adding the pointer, there is no copy. There is a retain, but that's another thing. Then if you make s point to another place that doesn't mean the array will also change it's pointer...

Answer (score 1):

The Java and Objective-C behaviors are the same. With the following Java code:

```
String foo = "foo";

Vector myVector = new Vector();
myVector.add(foo);

System.out.println(foo);
System.out.println(myVector);

foo = "bar";

System.out.println(foo);
System.out.println(myVector);
```

The following values are printed out:

```
foo
[foo]
bar
[foo]
```

Note: The same is true if I use String[] instead of Vector, but an NSArray is more like Vector than String[].

Comment: Thanks! Guess I'm just still a little confused about pointers (never used to think that way in Java).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see this is to see that your `s = @"B";` simply point s to another string object rather than modifying the original object.

So the array still contain @"A". When you add objects to NSArray you simply make a pointer in NSArray to point to @"A". That never changes.